# What can cause missing values aggregating polygon and raster data?

Tags: r, gis, r-raster, r-sf, r-stars

The aggregation (with `sf::aggregate()`) of polygon data with raster data generates a regular series of missing data.

[image]

Please consider the following code:

```
require(sf)
require(stars)

# Download here => http://www.filedropper.com/adaptorcamsregionalfcretrieve-15879390618606012-22402-6-64f0e215-609d-4ca6-b65c-a9ef7dc53370
raster_file <- 
  "adaptor.cams_regional_fc.retrieve-1587939061.8606012-22402-6-64f0e215-609d-4ca6-b65c-a9ef7dc53370.nc"

# Download here => https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fEhy3V4h1h5efDMrfa0x_mvnx2VL5T66/view?usp=sharing
polygon_file <-
  "hex_ita_1km.sf.RData"
r <- 
  read_stars(raster_file)
load(polygon_file)

st_crs(r) <- 4326
st_crs(hex_ita_1km.sf) <- st_crs(32632)
```

Please note that `r` doesn't contain any missing data in both variables

```
summary(r$pm10_conc)
summary(r$pm2p5_conc)
```

> ```
>  Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max.
> ```
>
> 0.08376   4.79556   9.77700  14.13988  18.06134 196.88487
>
> ```
> Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max.
> ```
>
> 0.05215  2.08035  4.39209  5.51724  7.46488 54.89545

```
a <- 
  aggregate(st_transform(r, 32632), 
            by = hex_ita_1km.sf, 
            FUN = mean)

plot(a, border = NA)
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @PalleDue The question is in the title

Comment: Sorry, missed that.

Comment: Download link doesn't work